# Messenger API: User is of mobile or desktop?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Is it possible to get the information from Messenger API that if the Messenger bot user is from a desktop device or a mobile device?

Comment: Person who voted for close might want to give some reason on why?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this isn't currently available. The only option is to check user-agent in the webview.